# Trying to allot Discord role when member messages role name

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

Trying to make a Discord.py bot that checks if there exists a role in the guild and give it to them when the member enters team name. The message will be like `INTRO, name of the person, team name (the role)`. I am getting the error `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'id'`, where am I going wrong?

```
        msg = str(message.content)
        msgspl = msg.split(", ", 2)
        role = msgspl[2] ## trying to get just the team name part
        if discord.utils.get(message.guild.roles, name=role): ## checking if it exists
            await message.author.add_roles(f"{role}")
            await message.channel.send("Thank you for introducing yourselves! The required roles have been allotted.")
        else:
            await message.channel.send(
                    "Hey! This team name doesn't exist in our records. Please recheck your team name and send the introduction message. If this issue persists, contact one of the admins.")
            await message.delete()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Hello!

So basically, I think that discord.py expects some kind of `discord.Role` object to be passed in `discord.Member.add_roles` (`message.author.add_roles`)

So you'll need to use the result from `discord.utils.get(message.guild.roles, name=role)` in `add_roles` in order for it to work.

This would also explain the error: `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'id'`: since you are passing a string (`str`) in `add_roles` (`f"{role}"`), the function expects to find a discord.Role object, which has an ID but gets a string which doesn't have the attribute `id`.

(Btw: you don't need to use f-strings here if you wanted the string representation, you could have just used `str(role)`)

##### Example fix

Assuming that what you've done before having the issue works, I would have written:

```py
role_name = message.content.split(", ", 2)[2] # message.content should be of type `str` according to the docs
role = discord.utils.get(message.guild.roles, name=role_name)
if role: ## checking if it exists
    await message.author.add_roles(role)
    await message.channel.send("Thank you for introducing yourselves! The required roles have been allotted.")
else:
    await message.channel.send("Hey! This team name doesn't exist in our records. Please recheck your team name and send the introduction message. If this issue persists, contact one of the admins.")
    await message.delete()
```

Let me know if it worked!

##### References

- `message.content` is of type `str`
  https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=message.guild#discord.Message.content
- `message.author.add_roles` parameters
  https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=message.guild#discord.Member.add_roles
- What we can expect from `discord.utils.get`
  https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=discord.utils.get#discord.utils.get
- `discord.Role` structure
  https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=message.guild#discord.Role